# Calculating reserves, and the 50% rule

Tags: warhammer-40k

According to the rules, 50% of units, rounded up may be in reserves. Also, some units (flyers, drop pods) don't count towards the units counted in reserves.

But do we count the latter including or excluding the units that don't count in reserves?

eg:

- A - 2 HQ (independent character)
- B - 1 unit in a drop pod (with space for the HQ)
- C - 2 units that can deep strike
- D - 2 units that can't start in reserves

  1. Do we count 50% of 7 units (=4), and we can thus put both A with the unit B (counts for 2), and also put both C in reserves (count for 2), only fielding both units D at the start. This also means that we only actually fielded 28% of the army.
  2. Do we count 50% of 6 units (B excluded), and thus can basically field like above except for either one HQ or one C. In this case we actually only field actually 43% of the army.

We played our last game according to case n°1. Were we wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rulebook pages on Deep Strike (p.36), I think the relevant rule-- for the sake of calculating 50%--is:

> When working out how many units can be placed in reserve, units that
>   must be deployed by Deep Strike (along with any models embarked upon
>   them) are ignored.

To apply to your situation, take your entire army and subtract (put aside mentally or physically) all the units that *must* be Deep Striking.  Whatever remains is the value that helps you determine 50%, so in this case corresponds to Case #2, 3 units (50 percent of 6 units) is your maximum reserve capacity.

**EDIT:** According to the General Rulebook FAQ v1.5, this is clarified further:

```
Q: Do units that are transported in a vehicle that MUST start in
reserve count towards the number of units that can be placed in
Reserves? For example, must I count the units in a Drop Pod or
Valkyrie towards the 50% of units I can place in Reserves?
(p124)
A: No.
```